# Write the type of a pointer to member data from other template types

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

I have a function that extracts pointer to member type from other types, and this works:

```
template<class T2, class Array,
    class Element = typename std::decay_t<Array>::element,
    class PointerToMemberType = T2 Element::*
>
v f(Array&& a, PointerToMemberType pm);
```

However I cannot find the way to write `PointerToMemberType = ???`, without first definining `Element`, which should be able to be omitted.

**How can I write `PointerToMemberType` directly without using the auxiliary `Element`?**

I tried plain substitution but it doesn't work:

```
template<
    class T2, class Array, 
    class PointerToMemberType = T2 typename std::decay_t<Array>::element::*
>
void f(Array&&, PointerToMemberType pm);
// error: expected identifier before ‘*’ token
  677 |  class PointerToMemberType = T2 typename std::decay_t<Array>::element::* 
                                                                               ^
```

I also tried adding `typename` and parenthesis in several places.

Note that `PointerToMemberType` is not used for deduction at the moment, although I would try to use it in the future.

**In some places it recommends using `std::invoke` so one doesn't need to deal with pointers-to-data-members, How would that fit or simplify something here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A helper metafunction would do the trick quite nicely:

```
template <typename C, typename M>
using PM = M C::*;

template<
    class T2, class Array, 
    class PointerToMemberType = PM<typename std::decay_t<Array>::element, T2>
>
...
```

As for whether it can be done "directly", the answer is yes, but you must *omit* the `typename` keyword. Your compiler should accept this:

```
template<
    class T2, class Array, 
    class PointerToMemberType = T2 std::decay_t<Array>::element::*
>
...
```

According to the standard, [temp.res]/5:

> A qualified name used as the name in a *class-or-decltype* (Clause 13) or an *elaborated-type-specifier* is
>   implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword. In a *nested-name-specifier*
>   that immediately contains a *nested-name-specifier* that depends on a template parameter, the *identifier* or
>   *simple-template-id* is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword. [ *Note:*
>   The `typename` keyword is not permitted by the syntax of these constructs. — *end note* ]

In our situation, we have the *nested-name-specifier* `std::decay_t<Array>::element::` which immediately contains the *nested-name-specifier* `std::decay_t<Array>::` which depends on a template parameter, so this paragraph tells us that `typename` is not necessary. Clearly, when `std::decay_t<Array>::element` is followed by `::`, the compiler knows that `std::decay_t<Array>::element` is a type and not a data member nor a member function.

According to the note, the grammar forbids the unnecessary use of `typename` in this situation. The proper use of a *typename-specifier* according to [temp.res]/3 is:

> `typename` *nested-name-specifier* *identifier*

Here, `typename` applies to the *identifier* after the entire *nested-name-specifier* has been applied, for example, in `typename A::B::C::D`, the `::` operator binds more tightly than `typename`, so you are saying that `typename A::B::C::D` is a type. A *nested-name-specifier* cannot contain `typename` at the top level of one of its components, since from [expr.prim.id.qual], the leftmost component can only be a *type-name*, a *namespace-name*, or a *decltype-specifier*, and a *type-name* (unlike a *type-id*) can only be an unqualified name or a *simple-template-id*. Non-leftmost components can only be unqualified names or *simple-template-id*s (sometimes required to be prefixed by `template`).

Comment: Uff, I missed that. Actually it failed in another context because it was trying to instantiate a pointer to member of a built-in type, which is not possible.

Comment: I found that is some cases I need the intermediate definition anyway in order to activate Sfinae for built-in types and not get a hard error.